# font not visible in attributs inspector in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with the addition of font in xcode. my font is well added in my computer, I did the ctrl drag and target my project, I added it in the fonts providded by app, it is in copy bundle resources but impossible to see in the inspector attributes in the storyboard.
Thanks for your help[font not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sysub.png)[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRu4z.png)

Answer (score 0):

apple has a doc to add new fonts
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

you must be sure that the name of your fonts should be the same in the info.plist file, some times the font name doesn't the real name.

use this code to know the real name of your fonts, this real name should be in info.plist file

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

Comment: thank you and i have do this and the name is the same .

Comment: @stork are you sure when drag the fonts to Xcode, you selected: copy files if is necessary? other issue, can be that the target membership of the font isn't select. the format aceptable for Xcode is Ott and ttf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add fonts to target in the `file inspector` to see them in the `attributes inspector`:

[image: Demo]